# Basic simple tokenizer

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to write a basic simple tokenizer using C.
I have a problem in the algorithm and the string token doesn't point to the correct token.

**Here is my implementation**:

```
char *test="root/ahmed/tolba";

Tokenize(test, '/');

...

void Tokenize(char* String, char Split)
{
    char *strings = String;
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; String[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (String[i] == Split)
        {
            const char * token = &strings[j];
            size_t length = i-j;
            j=i+1;
            printf(token);
        }           
    }           
}
```

Comment: What is the contents of `String`? What is the value of `Split`? Can you please elaborate on the expected and actual output?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have edited the post, please take a look at the code

Comment: "Can you please elaborate on the expected and actual output?"

Comment: Do yourself a favor and just use `strtok_r()`/strtok_s()` rather than re-inventing the wheel. Your code will become even messier when you try to account for leading/trailing slashes, ie `/root/.../`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to see what you're asking, but probably you want to print strings `token` with length `length`?

Use printf as follows:

```
printf("%.*s\n", length, token);
```

That syntax  (`%.*s`) allows you to specify the  amount to print.

Comment: the problem that token doesn't really point to the correct token, I need it holds the current token without pointing to its length

Answer (score 0):

> the problem that token doesn't really point to the correct token, I
>   need it holds the current token without pointing to its length

I have no idea what you mean by that. But this is a version I just quickly hacked together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Tokenize(char*string,char split)
{
        size_t last_length;
        char*begin = string,*end;

        /*Search for all occurances.*/
        while((last_length = strlen(begin))
        && (end = memchr(begin,split,last_length)))
        {
                printf("%.*s\n",(int)(end - begin),begin);
                begin = end + 1;
        }

        /*Print rest.*/
        if(last_length)
        {
                printf("%.*s\n",(int)last_length,begin);
        }
}

int main(void)
{
        char *test="root/ahmed/tolba";

        Tokenize(test, '/');
}
```

As I said, just quickly hacked together, but it should do.
If that does not help you, I am afraid you will have to try to polish your english and describe exactly what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the following code can help you. Its the modified form of your code.

```
void showToken(char *  String, char Split){
        int elementNumber,tokenPtr;
        char *token;
        for ( elementNumber = 0, tokenPtr = 0; String[elementNumber] != 0; elementNumber++){
                if ( String[elementNumber] == ' ' )
                {
                        token = &String[tokenPtr];
                        fprintf(stderr,"%.*s\n",(elementNumber-tokenPtr), token);
                        tokenPtr = elementNumber+1;
                }
        }
        token = &String[tokenPtr];
        fprintf(stderr,"%.*s\n",(elementNumber-tokenPtr), token);
        tokenPtr = elementNumber;
}
```